# Play video stream using Vitamio library in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, vitamio

I'm using the library Vitamio to play rtsp live stream. I tried to run the demo videoview class play rtsp link as follows:

[http://117.103.224.75:1935/live/*definst*/VTCHD3/VTCHD3_840x480_1200kbps.stream/playlist.m3u8](http://117.103.224.75:1935/live/_definst_/VTCHD3/VTCHD3_840x480_1200kbps.stream/playlist.m3u8)

==> Result : it run but quality very bad, load videos very low and picture in video are not sharp and sound are not heard. I don't know what to do to make it run smooth and picture is sharp. Please help me this problem ! Thank very much !

this is my code :

```
private String path="http://117.103.224.75:1935/live/_definst_/VTCHD3/VTCHD3_840x480_1200kbps.stream/playlist.m3u8";

private ProgressDialog prodlg;
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    prodlg=new ProgressDialog(this);
    prodlg.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    prodlg.setMessage("wating...");
    prodlg.show();

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    if (path == "") {
        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
        Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path" + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
        mVideoView.setBufferSize(2048);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                prodlg.dismiss();
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I use android platforms 4.0 api 14 play demo : 
[this is my screen picture demo](http://i59.tinypic.com/2ms0weh.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Vitamio library for displaying video etc, then first of all download Vitamio Library from here [Free download Vitamio Library](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle).
then include both "ZI" and "InitActivtiy" (which is inside the Vitamio lib) Library in your current project (right click project-->include library-->), then write this line of code

```
 if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
```

after Oncreate Method() like in my project.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)) //it will check the include library of Vitamio
        return;
```

after that put this line of code in Androidmanifest.xml file

```
  <!-- (((((( Vitamio Library including in manifest file )))))) -->
   <activity android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity" 
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
       android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Now its a time to display your video using VideoView etc.

Comment: "//Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path" how to put file path in this comment. it is require or not?